# python multiprocessing pool - wrong number of workers created

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, pool

I use multiprocessing Pool to divide tasks between different processes.
I noticed a strange behavior that only half of the expected workers start working after calling map_async.

That is, when I call

```
pool = Pool(12, init_func, (pram1, param2, param3))
pool.map_async(main_process_func, list_of_items, chunksize=1)
```

I see that actually 6 workers start executing main_process_func!

But when I add the parameter maxtasksperchild=1, that is:

```
pool = Pool(12, init_func, (pram1, param2, param3), maxtasksperchild=1)
pool.map_async(main_process_func, list_of_items, chunksize=1)
```

Then I see that 12 workers start executing main_process_func!

The maxtasksperchild should be unrelated to this behavior from my understanding.
Why do you think this is happening? And why in the first place only half of the workers start running?

Python version: 3.6.9
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4

Comment: Could you add a little info about how you are determining the number of workers that start?  E.g. does main_process_func print something as it starts or are you looking at the OS process IDs with a bash command?

Comment: Exactly. the first line of code in main_process_func is to print a message. I see that the number of messages printed is 6, and not 12. 
I do see 13 processes (1 main + 12 workers), but only 6 of the workers start working. Interestingly, when one of them finishes the current task it does, I see a new message being printed, that is it takes the following item from the queue.